# gradle maven-publish plugin adds timestamp, how to avoid putting it into suffix

Tags: java, maven, gradle, nexus

I'm using the 'maven-publish' plugin by gGradle and it putting a suffix after actual version, which I want to avoid. because in the next step of my CI it trying to download the .jar and the curl command is downloading nothing.

I can connect to my nexus and upload via `./gradlew publish Optional<VERSION=0.0.1>` but the plugin (I think) is added a timestamp, is looking like this:

```
a/b/c/ARTIFACT-NAME/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ARTIFACT-NAME-0.0.1-20190114.134142-8.jar
```

#### How can I disable the feature of timestamp in the plugin?

That's my publishing task:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            if (project.version.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT')) {
                url deployNexusSnapshotUrl
            } else {
                url deployNexusReleaseUrl
            }
            credentials {
                username = deployNexusUsername
                password = deployNexusPassword
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because you are publishing a `SNAPSHOT` version. This timestamp is a feature that allows to distinguish between different snapshot builds e.g. to use them for limited period of time and purge them later. It won't happen when you release a proper artifact version that doesn't use `-SNAPSHOT` suffix.

For the sake of CI build reproducibility you should never use `SNAPSHOT` dependencies when you are building software on CI. `SNAPSHOT` versions can be overridden especially if you disable the timestamp in the version.

What if there were no code changes in your project, the CI build was green but on the next day someone overwrites a `SNAPSHOT` dependency in repository and the build is now red? What if on the next day you have to release a hotfix to resolve urgent production issue but instead you have to focus on a problem introduced by new `SNAPSHOT` dependency.

You are trying to solve the wrong problem. `SNAPSHOT` is intended for local development only.

Comment: thx for the comprehensive idea! But if you want test the code and build on the branch in a define stage... what about that?

Comment: one generally doesn't publish from a feature branch. Most CI solutions allows to change the pipeline steps depending on branch name, IMO just remove publishing step on branch.

Comment: You don't answer the question. This statement is up for debate: "you should never use SNAPSHOT dependencies when you are building software on CI." At my organization, we always want people to use the latest version no matter what. It's not worth the storage cost of keeping every single build in maven. We don't send red builds to maven. We need a way to store only the latest snapshot and forget about previous versions with timestamps. This is possible with maven, but we can't find a way to do it with gradle.

Comment: does not answer the question

Comment: Yes there shouldn't be projects which are based on other snapshot artifacts but there is another real use case with security checks than Drew's.. What will you do if you are dealing with artifactory scan tools which are working with artifactory? They need existing artifacts in artifactory.. So publishing snapshot artifacts from our local machines (maybe from CI) to the artifcatory and then passing the artifact name to that tools is a requirement. Is there a way to learn exact artifact name with timestamp, buildnumber etc.. (for snapshot) in local before publishing it? It would be very good.